# SSH Command Execution Hangs, although interactive shell functions fine

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-execution

When I attempt to execute a command on a remote server with ssh, the ssh command hangs after the `exec request accepted` debug message, and eventually times out.

The failing command: `ssh -v -v <username>@<server> uptime` (also tried `echo hello` etc.)

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <server> (<ip>:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending command: uptime
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
```

And there it hangs, indefinitely.

When I ssh without a command into my remote server, however, I get an interactive shell and all is good.

Successful Command: `ssh -v -v <username>@<server>`

Output:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <server> (<ip>:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome!
<prompt>%
...
```

Has anyone an idea why an interactive session would be successful but a command execution not?

Has been haunting me for months now because I cannot use unison to sync my files any more (it used to work). Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I have an idea. Maybe there is a misconfiguration in your SSH client or on the SSH server. Try a different client to the same server, and then try the same client to a different server, and let's see which one works.

Comment: Some similar problems have been previously posted on stackoverflow: http://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+command+execution+hangs

Comment: It is not an SSH configuration issue - it fails from different clients. The server configuration is locked for me, but verified by other users. The other problems posted here are not exactly the same, I've looked through them.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem was indeed my login script, although not to do with requiring a terminal (I'd suspected that and tested with the `-t` and `-T` options). The problem was that my `.bashrc` was running an `exec` (in this case to `zsh` - because our system doesn't allow `chsh` to `zsh`).

The offending line:

```bash
test -f /usr/bin/zsh && exec /usr/bin/zsh
```

Solved by first checking for interactive shell and exiting if so:

```bash
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
test -f /usr/bin/zsh && exec /usr/bin/zsh
```

So, essentially, because the shell was execing into `zsh`, `ssh` was waiting for this to finish - which never happened.

I am a little confused why my `.bashrc` was being called at all - I thought this was only for interactive shells, but the exact purpose and order of the various init scripts is something I don't think I'll ever learn.

I hope this can be useful to others who have some kind of `exec` in their startup scripts.

BTW - the other two answers were on the right track so I was completely unsure if I should 'answer' or just comment their answers. If answering my own question is morally wrong on stackoverflow, let me know and I'll do penitence. Thank you to the other answerers.

Comment: .bashrc = called whenever the shell is invoked and attached to a terminal. .bash_profile is only invoked on login. The distinction is vague, but easily checked by echo 'echo I am logged in' > ~/.bash_profile and executing a command using ssh. That way you can see if direct command execution over ssh does or does not make the shell a login shell.

Comment: I was running into the exact same problem using oh-my-zsh, I had to insert `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` right before `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` to avoid SSH hanging when using another host as a proxy

Answer (score 6):

We fixed this by adding adding -n (to redirect std in from /dev/null) and -t (force pseudo-tty allocation)

Example:

```
ssh -t -n user@host command
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem most likely lies in your shell startup or shell logout scripts. Without knowing what's in there, it's hard to guess the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered a problem with the same symptoms, but determined that the issue was *not* a problem in my login scripts.  Rather, my local `.ssh/config` file was configured with `RequestTTY force` for the host that I was trying to copy to.

Answer (score 2):

Check for commands in your shell startup files (I would assume `~/.cshrc` from your prompt; in a non-interactive session, `~/.login` shouldn't matter) that require a terminal for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on fedora server 22, after the resolution of other new problems.

ssh **-t** ziimp /bin/true was ok but not ssh ziimp /bin/true and all my git+ssh and scp were locked.

The solution i found was in the **authorized_keys** file. I had to remove the command="/usr/bin/bash" prefix from my trusted keys...

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the "$-" var which works for me:

```bash
if [[ $- =~ i ]] ; then
    [ -x /bin/tcsh ] && exec /bin/tcsh
    # Bash startup stuff goes here...
fi
```

Got this from:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html